# Unable to add store at file in swift

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data

When I add CoreDataStack.swift into my project, I got this alarm information
**"unable to add store at file:///Users/mading/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5BA8936-0256-4B65-92C5-4D3C15653097/data/Containers/Data/Application/46843EC2-B9FF-4AD4-A789-5FFD85525735/Documents/model.sqlite."**
[image]

I tired to access to model.sqlite by the url

### file:///Users/mading/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5BA8936-0256-4B65-92C5-4D3C15653097/data/Containers/Data/Application/46843EC2-B9FF-4AD4-A789-5FFD85525735/Documents/model.sqlite

in terminal. 
And I found that there was no 46843EC2-B9FF-4AD4-A789-5FFD85525735 in the Application 
[image]
What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: The project is on the unableToAddStoreAtFile branch.
https://github.com/MartinSnow/ChinaWeather

Comment: What is `CoreDataStack.swift`? That's where the error is happening.

Comment: Also, if your code is throwing an error, you should print out that error. It usually has information that's necessary to solve the problem.